# Mindmaps: children of scopes' children, shared children and edge color gradient

Tags: mindmaps

I have some doubts regarding mindmaps. I am following the next templates:

[Scientific interactions](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/scientific-interactions/)

[Computer science mindmap](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/computer-science-mindmap/)

I do not seem to be able to interchange the 2 codes. The two main problems I am facing are:

1- make child nodes for the children like in the 2nd link, in particular 2 for 'a3' and 3 for 'b3'.

2- make gradient colors for the edges like in the 2nd link.

I also feel like 'c' should be a child of 'a' instead of a different scope, since they are connected, which takes me to problem 1. A plus would be to rearrange the whole network to make it look more beautiful (with fewer edge crossings) and smaller (less height, in particular), with shorter edges.

Please check the MWE below, any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,times}
\usepackage[paperwidth=25cm,paperheight=22cm,left=1cm,top=1cm]{geometry}

\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,backgrounds}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}



    \begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,
     level 1 concept/.append style={level distance=130,sibling angle=30}]
     \begin{scope}[mindmap, concept color=gray]
     \node [concept, ball color=red!50!black, scale=0.375] (a) {a}[clockwise from=-10] 
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (a1) {a1}}
        child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black, scale=0.6] (a2) {a2}}
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (a3) {a3}}
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (a4) {a4}}
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (a5) {a5}}
        child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black, scale=0.6] (a6) {a6}};
     \end{scope}

     \begin{scope}[mindmap, concept color=gray]
     \node [concept, ball color=red!50!black, scale=0.375] (b) at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3cm]a.east) {b}[clockwise from=50]
        child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black, scale=0.6] (b1) {b1}}
        child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black, scale=0.6] (b2) {b2}}
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (b3) {b3}}
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (b4) {b4}};
     \end{scope}

     \begin{scope}[mindmap, concept color=gray]
     \node [concept, scale=0.375] (c) at ([xshift=-2cm,yshift=2cm]a.east) {c}[clockwise from=180]
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (c1) {c1}}
        child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black, scale=0.6] (c2) {c2}}
        child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black, scale=0.6] (c3) {c3}};
     \end{scope}

     \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
     \draw [circle connection bar]
        (a4) edge (a5)
        (a1) edge (b)
        (a1) edge (b4)
        (a6) edge (b)
        (a) edge (c)
        (a5) edge (c)
        (b1) edge (c)
        (c1) edge (c3)
        (b1) edge (c);
     \end{pgfonlayer}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It produces the following:

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Nest `child {node {}}` constructs where required; I produced two children for `a3` and three for `b3`, as requested.
2. You can use

   ```
   circle connection bar switch color=from (<start color>) to (<endcolor>)
   ```

   see the paths at the end of my exmaple code.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,times}
\usepackage[paperwidth=25cm,paperheight=22cm,left=1cm,top=1cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,backgrounds}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,
     level 1 concept/.append style={level distance=130,sibling angle=30}]
     \begin{scope}[mindmap, concept color=gray,circle connection bar switch color=from (red) to (blue)]
     \node [concept, ball color=red!50!black, scale=0.375] (a) {a}[clockwise from=-10] 
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (a1) {a1}}
        child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black, scale=0.6] (a2) {a2}}
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (a3) {a3}
                     child {node[concept,scale=0.4]  (a31) {a31}}
                     child {node[concept,scale=0.4]  (a32) {a32}}
        }
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (a4) {a4}}
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (a5) {a5}}
        child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black, scale=0.6] (a6) {a6} 
        };
     \end{scope}

     \begin{scope}[mindmap, concept color=gray]
     \node [concept, ball color=red!50!black, scale=0.375] (b) at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3cm]a.east) {b}[clockwise from=50]
        child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black, scale=0.6] (b1) {b1}}
        child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black, scale=0.6] (b2) {b2}}
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (b3) {b3}
                child {node[concept,scale=0.4]  (b31) {b31}}
                child {node[concept,scale=0.4]  (b32) {b32}}
                child {node[concept,scale=0.4]  (b33) {b33}}
         }
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (b4) {b4}};
     \end{scope}

     \begin{scope}[mindmap, concept color=gray]
     \node [concept, scale=0.375] (c) at ([xshift=-2cm,yshift=2cm]a.east) {c}[clockwise from=180]
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (c1) {c1}}
        child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black, scale=0.6] (c2) {c2}}
        child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black, scale=0.6] (c3) {c3}};
     \end{scope}

     \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
     \path [circle connection bar]
        (a4) edge (a5)
        (a1) edge (b)
        (a1) edge (b4)
        (a6) edge (b)
        (a) edge (c)
        (a5) edge (c)
        (b1) edge (c)
        (c1) edge (c3)
        (b1) edge (c);
     \end{pgfonlayer}
    \path 
        (b) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (red!80!black) to (green!85!black)] (b2);
    \path 
        (b) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (red!80!black) to (green!85!black)] (b1);
    \path 
        (a) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (red!80!black) to (green!85!black)] (a2);
    \path 
        (a) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (red!80!black) to (green!85!black)] (a6);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I propose here some modifications:

1. Use a `small mindmap` instead of those scaling factors and enlarge the font (this I say for experience: reading the font with your original settings was a torture).
2. Change the position of some of the children; this improves a lot the aspect, since you can avoid some many crossing connectors; in particular the `grow=<angle>` option for child can be really useful here (see `a6` and `c2` in the code below).

The modified code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,times}
\usepackage[paperwidth=23cm,paperheight=22cm,left=1cm,top=1cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,backgrounds}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[small mindmap,every node/.append style={font=\large},
     level 1 concept/.append style={level distance=130,sibling angle=30}]
     \begin{scope}[mindmap, concept color=gray,circle connection bar switch color=from (red) to (blue)]
     \node [concept, ball color=red!50!black] (a) {a}[clockwise from=-10] 
        child {node [concept] (a1) {a1}}
        child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black] (a2) {a2}}
        child {node [concept] (a3) {a3}
                     child {node[concept]  (a31) {a31}}
                     child {node[concept]  (a32) {a32}}
        }
        child {node [concept] (a4) {a4}}
        child {node [concept] (a5) {a5}}
        child[grow=75] {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black] (a6) {a6} 
        };
     \end{scope}

     \begin{scope}[mindmap, concept color=gray]
     \node [concept, ball color=red!50!black] (b) at ([xshift=3cm,yshift=2cm]a.east) {b}[clockwise from=50]
        child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black] (b1) {b1}}
        child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black] (b2) {b2}}
        child {node [concept] (b3) {b3}
                child {node[concept]  (b31) {b31}}
                child {node[concept]  (b32) {b32}}
                child {node[concept]  (b33) {b33}}
         }
        child {node [concept] (b4) {b4}};
     \end{scope}

     \begin{scope}[mindmap, concept color=gray]
     \node [concept] (c) at ([xshift=-3cm,yshift=6cm]a.east) {c}[clockwise from=180]
        child {node [concept] (c1) {c1}}
        child[grow=45] {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black] (c2) {c2}}
        child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black] (c3) {c3}};
     \end{scope}

     \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
     \path [circle connection bar]
        (a4) edge (a5)
        (a1) edge (b)
        (a1) edge (b4)
        (a6) edge (b)
        (a) edge (c)
        (a5) edge (c)
        (b1) edge (c)
        (c1) edge (c3)
        (b1) edge (c);
     \end{pgfonlayer}
    \path 
        (b) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (red!80!black) to (green!85!black)] (b2);
    \path 
        (b) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (red!80!black) to (green!85!black)] (b1);
    \path 
        (a) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (red!80!black) to (green!85!black)] (a2);
    \path 
        (a) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (red!80!black) to (green!85!black)] (a6);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

And a variation in which `c` is a child of `a` (you'll have to decide whether this is the case or not):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,times}
\usepackage[paperwidth=23cm,paperheight=22cm,left=1cm,top=1cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,backgrounds}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[small mindmap,every node/.append style={font=\large},
     level 1 concept/.append style={level distance=130,sibling angle=30}]
     \begin{scope}[mindmap, concept color=gray,circle connection bar switch color=from (red) to (blue)]
     \node [concept, ball color=red!50!black] (a) {a}[clockwise from=-10] 
        child {node [concept] (a1) {a1}}
        child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black] (a2) {a2}}
        child {node [concept] (a3) {a3}
                     child {node[concept]  (a31) {a31}}
                     child {node[concept]  (a32) {a32}}
        }
        child {node [concept] (a4) {a4}}
        child {node [concept] (a5) {a5}}
        child[grow=120] {node[concept] (c) {c}
            child {node [concept] (c1) {c1}}
           child[grow=45] {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black] (c2) {c2}}
           child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black] (c3) {c3}}
            }
        child[grow=55] {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black] (a6) {a6} 
        };
     \end{scope}

     \begin{scope}[mindmap, concept color=gray]
     \node [concept, ball color=red!50!black] (b) at ([xshift=4cm,yshift=2cm]a.east) {b}[clockwise from=50]
        child[grow=110] {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black] (b1) {b1}}
        child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black] (b2) {b2}}
        child {node [concept] (b3) {b3}
                child {node[concept]  (b31) {b31}}
                child {node[concept]  (b32) {b32}}
                child {node[concept]  (b33) {b33}}
         }
        child {node [concept] (b4) {b4}};
     \end{scope}

     \begin{scope}[mindmap, concept color=gray]
%     \node [concept] (c) at ([xshift=-3cm,yshift=6cm]a.east) {c}[clockwise from=180]
%        child {node [concept] (c1) {c1}}
%        child[grow=45] {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black] (c2) {c2}}
%        child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black] (c3) {c3}};
     \end{scope}

     \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
     \path [circle connection bar]
        (a4) edge (a5)
        (a1) edge (b)
        (a1) edge (b4)
        (a6) edge (b)
        (a) edge (c)
        (a5) edge (c)
        (b1) edge (c)
 %       (c1) edge (c3)
        (b1) edge (c);
     \end{pgfonlayer}
    \path 
        (b) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (red!80!black) to (green!85!black)] (b2);
    \path 
        (b) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (red!80!black) to (green!85!black)] (b1);
    \path 
        (a) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (red!80!black) to (green!85!black)] (a2);
    \path 
        (a) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (red!80!black) to (green!85!black)] (a6);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adding a solid (i.e., not shaded) color for selected connection bars seems not to be as immediate as I thought; in the following example I defined a `connection bar color` key allowing to assign solid colors (although one could use `circle connection bar switch color=from (<color>) to (<color>)` but this could be computationally heavy since behind the scenes it is a shading):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,times}
\usepackage[paperwidth=23cm,paperheight=22cm,left=1cm,top=1cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,backgrounds}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[small mindmap,every node/.append style={font=\large},
     level 1 concept/.append style={level distance=130,sibling angle=30},
     connection bar color/.style={every circle connection bar/.append style={
            append after command={[fill=#1]}}}]
     \begin{scope}[mindmap, concept color=gray,circle connection bar switch color=from (red) to (blue)]
     \node [concept, ball color=red!50!black] (a) {a}[clockwise from=-10] 
        child {node [concept] (a1) {a1}}
        child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black] (a2) {a2}}
        child {node [concept] (a3) {a3}
                     child {node[concept]  (a31) {a31}}
                     child {node[concept]  (a32) {a32}}
        }
        child {node [concept] (a4) {a4}}
        child {node [concept] (a5) {a5}}
        child[grow=120] {node[concept] (c) {c}
            child {node [concept] (c1) {c1}}
           child[grow=45] {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black] (c2) {c2}}
           child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black] (c3) {c3}}
            }
        child[grow=55] {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black] (a6) {a6} 
        };
     \end{scope}

     \begin{scope}[mindmap, concept color=gray]
     \node [concept, ball color=red!50!black] (b) at ([xshift=4cm,yshift=2cm]a.east) {b}[clockwise from=50]
        child[grow=110] {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black] (b1) {b1}}
        child {node [concept, ball color=green!25!black] (b2) {b2}}
        child {node [concept] (b3) {b3}
                child {node[concept]  (b31) {b31}}
                child {node[concept]  (b32) {b32}}
                child {node[concept]  (b33) {b33}}
         }
        child {node [concept] (b4) {b4}};
     \end{scope}


    \path 
        (b) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (red!80!black) to (green!85!black)] (b2);
    \path 
        (b) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (red!80!black) to (green!85!black)] (b1);
    \path 
        (a) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (red!80!black) to (green!85!black)] (a2);
\begin{scope}[circle connection bar,connection bar color=cyan!70!black]
    \path 
        (a4) to (a5);
    \path 
        (a1) to (b);
    \path 
        (a1) to (b4);
\end{scope}        
    \path 
        (a6) to (b);
\begin{scope}[circle connection bar,connection bar color=orange!70!black]
    \path 
        (a5) to (c);
    \path 
        (b1) to (c);
    \path 
        (c1) to (c3);
    \path 
        (b1) to (c);
\end{scope}        
    \path 
        (a) to[circle connection bar,connection bar color=yellow!70!black] (a3);
    \path 
        (a) to[circle connection bar,connection bar color=magenta!70!black] (a4);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many many thanks! and sorry for the small font. Exactly what I was looking for with a great distribution. Just a quick question, since I can specify the edges with the paths at the end, I can create the extra edges the same way and remove the whole \begin{pgfonlayer}{background} block, right? Then how could I color the edges just gray? I will play around... Thanks!

Comment: @DaniCee You're welcome! I just updated my answer adding an option in which `c` is a child of `a`. Regarding your question, I have to leave now in a hurry but in some hours I'll answer it.

Comment: Thanks again Gonzalo, really complete answer! As for the last question, one might think that "circle connection bar switch color=gray" or "circle connection bar color=gray" would work... I will leave it as "circle connection bar switch color=from (gray) to (gray)" for the moment, since I don't find anything better. Thanks again!

Comment: Another thing that I'm trying to do is rotate the whole network, I'm trying this http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Rotations with no success...

Comment: @DaniCee I've updated my answer showing how to assign colors to selected connection bars. Regarding the rotation, using `\rotatebox` from the `graphicx` package does the job. If you experience any difficulties, I'd suggest you to open a fresh new question.

Answer (score 3):

Another proposal. This solution makes `c` a child of `a` and children for `a3` and `b3` ared added. Also, a `concept color=blue, text=black` is defined for the parents node so that the gradient effect can be seen when a child has its own `concept color` (see child a3, b3 and c). You may want to remove the `ball color=<some color>` commands for a different possibility to explore. Note: `clockwise from=40` controls the first child node to start from 40 degree CW while `sibling angle=30` controls the sepration among children.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,times}
\usepackage[paperwidth=25cm,paperheight=22cm,left=1cm,top=1cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,backgrounds}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[mindmap, concept color=blue, text=black, 
level 1 concept/.append style={level distance=130,sibling angle=30},
level 2 concept/.append style={text=black,sibling angle=40}
]

node [concept, scale=0.375,ball color=red!50!black] (a) {a}[clockwise from=-30] 
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (a1) {a1}}
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6, ball color=green!25!black] (a2) {a2}}
%
        child [concept color=red]{node[concept, scale=0.6]  (a3) {a3}[clockwise from=-70]
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (a31) {a31}}
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (a32) {a32}}
}
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (a4) {a4}}
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (a5) {a5}}
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6, ball color=green!25!black] (a6) {a6}}
%
        child[concept color=green] {node [scale=0.6,concept,ball color=red!50!black] (c) at ([xshift=-3cm,yshift=3cm]a.east) {c}[clockwise from=180]
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (c1) {c1}}
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6,ball color=green!25!black,text=yellow] (c2) {c2}} 
%
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6, ball color=green!25!black,text=yellow] (c3) {c3}} 
%
}
node [concept, scale=0.375,ball color=red!50!black] (b) at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3cm]a.east) {b}[clockwise from=40]
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6, ball color=green!25!black] (b1) {b1}}
%
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6, ball color=green!25!black] (b2) {b2}}
%
        child[concept color=green] {node [concept, scale=0.6] (b3) {b3}[clockwise from=20]
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (b31) {b31}}
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (b32) {b32}}
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (b33) {b33}}
}
        child {node [concept, scale=0.6] (b4) {b4}};

     \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
     \draw [circle connection bar]
        (a4) edge (a5)
        (a1) edge (b)
        (a1) edge (b4)
        (a6) edge (b)
        (a) edge (c)
        (a5) edge (c)
        (b1) edge (c)
        (c1) edge (c3)
        (b1) edge (c);
     \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will explore this approach too, but will accept Gonzalo's answer mainly for the distribution. Thanks!